# Pandas extra columns are added

Tags: python, pandas

Why are the extra columns (the ones with the 1 values) added and how can I remove them?
Also is there anyway to make the two long lines shorter?
[Excel sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jf5u.png)

```
def sum_symp_by_gender():
    df = pd.read_csv('corona_tested_individuals.csv')
    df = df[['cough', 'fever', 'sore_throat', 'shortness_of_breath', 'head_ache', 'corona_result', 'gender']][df['cough'] == 1][df['fever'] == 1][df['sore_throat'] == 1][df['shortness_of_breath'] == 1][df['head_ache'] == 1][df['corona_result'] == 'חיובי']
    table = df.groupby(['gender', 'cough', 'fever', 'sore_throat', 'shortness_of_breath', 'head_ache']).agg(Cough=('cough', 'count'), Fever=('fever', 'count'), Sore_Throat=('sore_throat', 'count'), Shortness_Of_Breath=('shortness_of_breath', 'count'), Head_Ache=('head_ache', 'count'))
    table.to_csv('Sum of symptoms by gender.csv')
    return table
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't read your column names, but you can drop them like this. which two long lines ?

```
df.drop(['head_ache..', 'columnb','columnc'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: It actually gives me a key error when I try to use this line (I have added a clearer photo of the excel sheet).

And I meant lines 4 and 5. I was wondering if you can make them more compact.

Comment: can you copy-paste the full error message here.